# getExternalFilesDir Folder + Clear Data

Tags: android, database, sd-card

I am saving my database and some files in the `getExternalFilesDir()` .

Is it normal that when i go to `Settings>Applications>Manage applications->MyApp` and choose `Clear Data` the files still remain there?

Comment: if you are using getExternalFilesDir() then application related data will be deleted after uninstalling the application.

Comment: Yes i know, but i would like to know if i don't uninstall but only select `Clear Data` shouldn't the files be removed?

Comment: afaik it only removes the share preferences data.